# Regexp to match tag that contain specific word in class and has specific id

Tags: php, regex

Trying to match the tag section with a class, that contain some specific word and has id also, maybe some other tag attributes.

```
<section id="footer-widget-wysija-2" class="widget footer-widget widget_wysija">Some html</section>
```

Want to remove this section from html before render it.

Tried a lot of things, but no luck.
Any help will appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You say you've tried a lot of things, so what exactly have you tried? You don't want answers you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to operate with HTML documents is using a parser.

In these examples I will use built-in `DOMDocument`.

First of all, you have to init `DOMDocument` and load HTML string:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors( True );
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
libxml_use_internal_errors( False );
```

I use `->loadHTML` to load a string, but if your original HTML is in a file, you can directly use

```
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $yourFilePath );
```

To avoid annoying warnings about invalid HTML syntax,
I set `libxml_use_internal_errors( True )`.

#### Example 1: Delete all nodes with ‘section’ tag:

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'section' );
while( $nodes->length )
{
    $nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild( $nodes->item(0) );
}
```

With `->getElementsByTagName( 'section' )` I get all document's nodes with tag `section`, then — in the `while` loop — I delete each node. Note that I use `while` instead of `foreach`, because (if I have two `section` node, i.e.) when I delete first node, second node become first, and the following `foreach` loop will fail. As alternative, I can use a *decrementing* `for` loop.

#### Example 2: Delete node by ID:

```
if( $node = $dom->getElementById( 'footer-widget-wysija-1' ) )
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild( $node );
}
```

ID is unique by definition, so `->getElementById()` return only one element: if it is found, I can delete it using `->removeChild()`

#### Output HTML:

Finally, to output resulting HTML, you have to use

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I've just tried to solve this with regexp, as it should be 1-2 lines of code. Anyway, yes, your solution should work.

Comment: Read [this famous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3294262) about parsing html with regex. Regex is **never** a good practice to parse HTML. If in your `section` in future there are complex html (or a nested `section`) your regex will fail.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you dont have nested sections:

```
$html = preg_replace('#<section.+id="footer-widget-wysija-2".+</section>#is', '', $html);
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Just tried and again no luck. Getting only background of page and topmenu.
But anyway I want to make it a little better, because maybe cases when id will like `footer-widget-wysija-3`. Format of id should be `footer-widget-wysija-number`.